# mysql query stuck in sending data state when execured from java client (JdbcTemplate)

Tags: java, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, jdbctemplate

When i am trying to run below sql query on mysql server then mysql server is going into sending data state for forever

```
SELECT a.cust
     , a.job_num
     , a.fund_num
     , a.fund_type
     , a.process_type
     , a.code
     , a.mail_type
     , a.rec_date
     , a.mail_date
     , a.acc_num
     , a.add1
     , a.add2
     , a.add3
     , a.add4
     , a.add5
     , a.add5
     , a.add7
     , a.tax_num
     , a.data_source
     , a.sec_dec
     , a.serv_flag
     , a.add_ind
     , a.cons_id
     , a.cust_num
     , a.cust_name
     , (CASE when a.process_type='DAILY' 
            THEN (SELECT b.roll_num 
                    FROM db_daily_report b 
                   WHERE b.acc_num = a.acc_num 
                     AND b.cust_num = a.cust_num 
                     AND b.cons_id = a.cons_id 
                     AND b.WRITTEN_TO = 'OUTPUT') 
            When a.PROCESS_TYPE='ANNUAL' 
            THEN (SELECT c.roll_num 
                    FROM db_annual_report c 
                   WHERE c.acc_num = a.acc_num 
                     AND c.cust_num = a.cust_num 
                     AND c.cons_id = a.cons_id 
                     AND c.WRITTEN_TO = 'OUTPUT') 
                END) roll_num
     , a.pref
     , a.cons_id
     , a.cntry 
  FROM audit_customer a  
 WHERE DATE(a.mail_date) BETWEEN '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-05' 
   AND a.process_type = 'Annual' 
   AND a.fund_type IN (2) 
   AND a.mail_type IN ('F') 
 ORDER 
    BY a.created_ts DESC
```

explain on above query returns following result

> id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows,
> Extra
>
> '1', 'PRIMARY', 'a', 'index_merge',
> 'idx_audit_customer_fund_type,idx_audit_customer_process_type,idx_audit_customer_rec_date',
> 'idx_audit_customer_rec_date,idx_audit_customer_fund_type,idx_audit_customer_process_type',
> '3,4,23', NULL, '196048', 'Using
> intersect(idx_audit_customer_rec_date,idx_audit_customer_fund_type,idx_audit_customer_process_type);
> Using where; Using filesort'
>
> '3', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'c', 'ref',
> 'idx_db_annual_report_cust_name,idx_db_annual_report_acc_num,idx_db_annual_report_cons_id', 'idx_db_annual_report_acc_num', '63', 'cmhdb.a.acc_num', '16', 'Using
> where'
>
> '2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'b', 'ref',
> 'idx_db_daily_report_cust_name,idx_db_daily_report_acc_num,idx_db_daily_report_cons_id',
> 'idx_db_daily_report_acc_num', '63', 'db.a.acc_num', '16', 'Using
> where'

I am not able to understand why my query is stuck in sending_data state when I try to run

> SHOW_FULL_PROCESSLIST

command in mysql workbench

Comment: `a.cons_id b.WRITTEN_TO` is nonsense.

Comment: And what are all these backslash thingies?

Comment: updated question @Strawberry kindly check

Comment: I still see backslashes

Comment: Now check. my query is stuck in sending data state

Comment: Well, one thing to observe is that functions cannot use indexes, but anyway a comparison `BETWEEN '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-05'` is decidedly odd, don't you think?

Comment: should i use 2020-10-05<= and > 2020-10-05 instead of BETWEEN '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-05'? what difference it will make?

Comment: if I use 2020-10-05<= and > 2020-10-05 instead of BETWEEN '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-05 in query then explain on that query is not using index instead it is using where and using filesort

Answer (score 1):

Your case/when construct is off...  Your second WHEN is also using an alias "b", but the join condition is using alias "c" and probably throwing into a Cartesian result and choking on an every record to every record.

Also, not knowing your data, it will probably fail if either of those case/when select statements return more than one record.

FEEDBACK per request

Here is what I would change to.  You are running based on annual, so I removed the case/when and just set to a direct JOIN condition to your annual table.  If doing daily, I would have just change the table from the annual to your daily for the JOIN portion.

Also, to help optimize the query, I would have an index on  `(process_type, fund_type, mail_type, mail_date, created_ts )`

The where clause with the date is done in two parts instead of between.  Since you were using the date() function to strip off any time component of the record, that can not be optimized against an index.  So, my index above puts the other fields in higher priority and moved the date to the tail-end.  By doing a GREATER THAN or EQUAL to the '2020-10-05', you get everything on/after 12:00 midnight/morning of that date.  By also getting AND LESS THAN '2020-10-06', you are getting everything for the 10/5 date up to 11:59:59PM for that day, hence less than 10/6.  So now the index can be utilized inclusive of the date portion.

```
SELECT a.cust
     , a.job_num
     , a.fund_num
     , a.fund_type
     , a.process_type
     , a.code
     , a.mail_type
     , a.rec_date
     , a.mail_date
     , a.acc_num
     , a.add1
     , a.add2
     , a.add3
     , a.add4
     , a.add5
     , a.add5
     , a.add7
     , a.tax_num
     , a.data_source
     , a.sec_dec
     , a.serv_flag
     , a.add_ind
     , a.cons_id
     , a.cust_num
     , a.cust_name
     , c.roll_num
     , a.pref
     , a.cons_id
     , a.cntry 
  FROM 
     audit_customer a  
        JOIN db_annual_report c 
          on c.acc_num = a.acc_num 
         AND c.cust_num = a.cust_num 
         AND c.cons_id = a.cons_id 
         AND c.WRITTEN_TO = 'OUTPUT'

 WHERE 
       a.process_type = 'Annual' 
   AND a.fund_type IN (2) 
   AND a.mail_type IN ('F') 
   AND a.mail_date >= '2020-10-05' 
   and a.mail_date < '2020-10-06' 
 ORDER 
    BY a.created_ts DESC
```

Feedback #2

To add clarification of >= and < vs between.  Your original query was using the date() function call to get only the date portion from a date/time column. Using function calls in a where clause is not optimizable and can not be applied to an index.

So when you had `date(mail_date) between '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-05'`, you were essentially asking for only activity for the single date of 2020-10-05 regardless of morning, afternoon, or late at night, as long as the date was 2020-10-05.

To take advantage of an index on a datetime field that could be any time within the day, I am not using the date() function, but allowing the full date/time field to be part of the where clause by doing the explicit >= and <

So my from date/time is 2020-10-05 at 12:00:00 am (midnight from 2020-10-04 changing to 2020-10-05).  So, any activity as of the am even as early as 2020-10-05 12:00:01am (should activity be so early), would be included via the >= '2020-10-05'.  By not explicitly stating the time, the 12 midnight (am) is the default.

Now, the ENDING date range, I am explicitly doing LESS THAN the 2020-10-06.  This means it allows all the way up to 2020-10-05 to 11:59:59pm (just before midnight starting 2020-10-06).

If I did `date( mail_date ) between '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-06'`, I would get activity for BOTH dates.  Since you only cared about 1 day, the BETWEEN was not required and could have been done with `date( mail_date ) = '2020-10-05'` but would not have been optimized with an index either condition.

Does that help?  I don't think I can explain it any further.

Comment: @PawanPatil, if you updated, is it now working, or still crashing.  Also, for your case/when, will the select condition only ever give a single row for either the daily or annual query basis?  If so, I would rewrite the query slightly.

Comment: my query is stuck in sending data state @DRapp

Comment: @PawanPatil, does it work from the workbench or not.  If not, try to remove your column with the case/when to see if THAT is throwing it off.  Also, your WHERE clause is using 'Annual', but case is using 'ANNUAL', and you should not need \' for the dates, just the single quotes.  Let me know results.  Change you where clause to   a.mail_date >= '2020-10-05' and a.mail_date < '2020-10-06' so date-based index if any can be used.

Comment: can you add query in your answer which you are suggesting?

Comment: @PawanPatil, posted with revised query.

Comment: if I use 2020-10-05<= and > 2020-10-05 instead of BETWEEN '2020-10-05' and '2020-10-05 in query then explain on that query is not using index instead it is using where and using filesort

Comment: @PawanPatil, do you have an index based on the key I provided of the  (process_type, fund_type, mail_type, mail_date, created_ts ).  That will be used to optimize this query.

Comment: yes i have index on all five  columns process_type, fund_type, mail_type, mail_date, created_ts

Comment: @PawanPatil, the condition should be >= the start date and LESS than the following... mail_date >= '2020-10-05' AND mail_date < '2020-10-06'.  So, is your query now working?

Comment: my query is working but my question what difference does it make if I choose between and >= and < ?

Comment: @PawanPatil, re-clarified in answer.

Comment: In this condition i have one date . but this is not case everytime. I need to choose between two dates.

Comment: @PawanPatil,  Then I would wrap them in parens, such as AND (   ( mail_date >= firstDate AND mail_date < dayAfter) OR ( mail_date >= secondDate and mail_date < dayAfterSecond ) ).  Having more clarification on things like date ranges, multiple dates, etc would be good to have included in future questions.

Comment: i have midified query as suggested by you but still my query is tuck in sending data state

Comment: @PawanPatil, you say its stuck in the sending data state.  But also thought you mentioned the query worked from workbench.  Where is it failing on the sending data state.  You don't indicate any language you are trying to pull into, such as via C#, VB, java, php, etc.,  where is it failing, something may be on THAT end if the workbench query actually works.

Comment: my java application is waiting for forever to get a result from the MySQL database. when I run SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST it shows my query is always stuck at sending data set. however, query runs fine on MySQL workbench.

Comment: @PawanPatil, then I would post the JAVA portion as a new question.  Indicate you have a known working query from within Workbench, but it is hung getting the data.  A java specialist should be able to better help there.  But at least this answer has your query itself working... Correct?

Comment: my query was always working  even with when and case as well. problem is retrieving data from database to java client application we have 3 lkah record in this query and query is getting stuck at Sending data state always when executed from java client app.